# Lua redis call zrange returns string

Tags: lua, redis

I have a data at Redis with keyname hotels which is JSON format and when I try to get details in loop it returns string so that I can not check for example hotel.address)

```
local ks=redis.call('ZRANGE', 'hotels', '0', '-1')
local counter = 0
local hotels = {}
for _, hotel in ipairs(ks) do
    hotels[counter] = hotel
    counter = counter + 1 
   -- can not control like if(hotel.address == 'something') because of being string and don't want to handle with string comparison
end
```

I tried cjson.encode(hotels) but I'm not still able to access object items with .address or ["address"] (also can't use 3rd party libraries for working from redis.eval).

How can I work with json properly and controlling data in that data at lua file

Comment: You want `cjson.decode()` not `encode()`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but with that this error occurs .Bad argument #1 to 'decode' (string expected, got table) .Hotels = {} (table) can't decode hotels